# fopen() fails on /dev/ttyACM0

Tags: linux, fopen

I'm working on an embedded Linux (built via buildroot, not by me, but I have access to).
I'm connecting a cellular modem via USB, which creates ttyACM0 (and a few more ttyACMx).
I'm using pppd to run the modem - and it's working fine.

What I'm trying to do, is update the APN in the chatscript (before running the pppd), by asking "AT+CIMI" and parsing the network number within the response.

I tried [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/), a qute little c-language program, which works on my laptop (Ubuntu) and on another embedded Linux, but fails on this platform. It uses fopen().
I tried to pin-point the problem and found that fopen() fails with errno 5 (Input/Output error).
I changed to open() and it worked!!! I can send AT requests and view the recieved responses.

So - what's the deal?

*** PS - /dev is mounted as tmpfs, it runs busybox mdev (as apposed to devtmpfs by udev, on my laptop).

Thanks.

Comment: You can further investigate by comparing `strace` output of the version with `fopen()` and the one with `open()`; perhaps `open()` is called with different _flags_.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used a serial-port API with the Qt framework (it's a Qt app').
It is using the basic open()/write() API.